# Trying to connect a DB : Win7 Enterprise 64bit- Python cx_Oracle - oci.dll is not found

Tags: python, cx-oracle

python 3.6 64 bit,Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.4.0 - 64bit Production,cx_oracle 6.4.1

Able to connect DB thru sqlplus and sql developer manually.

when trying to connect through python:

cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: DPI-1047: 64-bit Oracle Client library cannot be loaded: "C:\Oracle\product\11.2.0\client_1\bin\oci.dll is not the correct architecture" ....

manually verified that 
"C:\Oracle\product\11.2.0\client_1\BIN\" has the oci.dll

Please help

Comment: You probably installed the 32-bit version?? Try installing the 64-bit version

Comment: You can't call a 32-bit DLL from a 64-bit executable. If you try you will only get an error message. This error message is one of the most explicit that I've seen. Mostly they are along the lines of *file not found* or *could not be loaded*.

Comment: both are 64 bit..i checked

Answer (score 0):

The DLL at C:\Oracle\product\11.2\client_1\bin\oci.dll is not a 64-bit DLL. You will need to download and extract a 64-bit Oracle Instant Client in order to resolve this issue. Note that the fact that the server is 64-bit is not relevant in this case. The client must be 64-bit!

Comment: Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.4.0 - 64bit Production i sthe version i have

Comment: Check the DLL at the location mentioned in the error message and make sure that is the one you installed. It is possible that you have multiple versions. Perhaps a database version and a client version?